# ArrayAdapter replaces list rather than update ListView

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I hope someone can help.

I have a Food Menu app. When the user opens the app they are presented with a list of food categories such as "Main Course". I am pulling this list from the Strings.xml file with string-array. When a category is selected it opens a second layout that displays the list of food items that can be chosen, my problem now is:

When they click an item such as Steak, it adds the Item to the selecteditems layout but if I go back to the ListMenu (by press the back button on the phone) and choose another item, it replaces the item I had selected earlier. How can I get it to append the new item?

Here are my files and code:

mainCoarse.java

```
package com.mycompany.lunch;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListMenu extends ListActivity {

List<String> itemordered = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maincoarsemain);
    final ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    final ArrayList<String> myNewList = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.maincoarse_menu,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            String item=lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
            String itemordered;
            itemordered = item + " added to list";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), itemordered, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            myNewList.add(item);
            ListView newList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menu_item);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListMenu.this, myNewList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            newList.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Launching new Activity on selecting List Item
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListItem.class);
            // sending data to new activity
            i.putExtra("item", item);
            startActivity(i);   
        }
        });
    }
}
```

ListItem.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListItem extends Activity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.selecteditems);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    ArrayList<String> myNewList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String item = i.getStringExtra("item");

    myNewList.add(item);
    ListView selecteditems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listitems);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListItem.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myNewList);
    selecteditems.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
}
```

I hava tried changing the line "myNewList.add(item);" to "myNewList.addAll(item);" but then I get the error: The method addAll(Collection) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (String)

selecteditems.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@drawable/main_background" 
  android:paddingLeft="10.0dip" 
  android:paddingTop="0.0dip" 
  android:paddingRight="10.0dip" 
  android:paddingBottom="10.0dip" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100.0dip"
            android:background="@drawable/title" />

        <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:background="@drawable/head" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="10.0dip" />    

          <ListView 
              android:id="@+id/listitems"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="25dip"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:padding="10dip"
              android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Summary: It adds the Item to the new selecteditems layout but if I go back to the ListMenu and choose another item, it replaces the item I had selected earlier.  How can I get it to append the new item?

Answer (score 1):

Set your adapter only once and when you want to update data

use `adapter.notifyDataSetChange();`

Comment: I only see the adapter set once "selecteditems.setAdapter(myadapter);"  I'm sorry, what I'm I messing up?

Answer (score 0):

When you select an item in MainCourse activity, save it into a database table and then fetch it back in List item activity. by this, every time when you move back to the previous activity and select one more item, it will be stored in database and you can fetch it back with the previous items in ListItem activity.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I understand that you would like to swap your ArrayAdapter by other arrays.

On your Adapter class extends by ArrayAdapter, put this two classes and call in your Activity swapItems(List)

```
public void swapItems(List<Object> newList){
    List<Object> oldList = this.getAllAdapterList();
    List<Object> swapList;
    if (newList.size() >= oldList.size()) {
        swapList = newList;
    } else {
        swapList = oldList;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<swapList.size();i++) {
        if (i < newList.size()) {
            this.insert(newList.get(i), i);
        }
        if(i < oldList.size()) {
            this.remove(oldList.get(i));
        }

    }

    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public List<Object> getAllAdapterList(){
    int count = this.getCount();
    List<Object> objVal = new ArrayList<Object>();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        objVal.add(this.getItem(i));
    }
    return objVal;
}
```